# How to update and get session value in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I am trying to update a dropdown box and two text box value in session and then get those session value in next page. For this I have written following code in my first page

```
<form action="/thanks" method="POST">

<select name="select_amount" id="select_amount" onchange="submit();">
   <option>-----</option>
   <option value="10">1st option</option>
   <option value="15">2nd option</option>
   <option value="20">3rd option</option>
   <option value="25">4th option</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="programname" /><br>
<input type="text" name="email" /><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button_add">

</form>

      <?php
            session_start();
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $_SESSION['pro']=$_POST['programname'];
            $_SESSION['e']=$_POST['email'];
            $_SESSION['amount']=$_POST['select_amount'];
       }?>
```

and in `thanks.php` file I am trying to get session value by following code

```
<?php
     session_start(); 
     if (isset($_SESSION['amount'])) {
     echo $_SESSION['amount'];
}?>
```

I have also added following code in my theme `function` file  but its not working.

```
if(!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}
```

Comment: and the question is ?

Comment: To use cookie-based sessions, `session_start()` must be called before outputing anything to the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`session_start()` is called after output is send to the browser which should result in an error being thrown. `session_start()` should be the first thing in your PHP file (after the starting tag).

You are trying to set the `session` variables on the same page the form is on. PHP code is not executed in the browser but on the server, the `$_POST` variable is thus only available once you submit the form.

What you probably meant to do is the following:

```
<?php
      session_start(); // start session before output
?>
<form action="/thanks" method="POST">

<select name="select_amount" id="select_amount" onchange="submit();">
   <option>-----</option>
   <option value="10">1st option</option>
   <option value="15">2nd option</option>
   <option value="20">3rd option</option>
   <option value="25">4th option</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="programname" /><br>
<input type="text" name="email" /><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button_add">

</form>
```

thanks.php

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // form is posted to this page
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        // form is posted to this page
        $_SESSION['amount'] = $_POST['select_amount'];
        $_SESSION['programname'] = $_POST['programname'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];

        echo $_SESSION['amount'];
    }
}?>
```